# Cocoa Touch - int as string format

Tags: cocoa-touch, integer

playerOneScore is a int, How can I pass it to use a label to display the score? This code just prints %i...

```
-(void)updateScoreLabels{
        playerOneScoreLabel.text = @"%i",playerOneScore;
        playerTwoScoreLabel.text = @"%i",playerTwoScore;
        playerThreeScoreLabel.text = @"%i",playerThreeScore;
        playerFourScoreLabel.text = @"%i",playerFourScore;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize string using convenience constructor:

```
playerOneScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",playerOneScore];
...
```

What you actually have in your code is [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) - it evaluates its 1st parameter (that is assigns @"%i" string to a label), then evaluates and returns 2nd parameter - playerOneScore.